# What is the sense/meaning of this 着？

Tags: meaning

我希望你们都有一个愉快的假期！ 国庆节快乐！

When I read this, I assumed 扎着 was zha1zhe, but when I listened she says zha1zhao2.

快结束时我看你微微甩了甩手，你平时被东西扎着时就是这个样子。
Near the end I saw you give a little flick of the hand; when something pricks you, you always react like that.

What effect does 着 zhao2 have on 扎？ Is it translatable?

I got this from mdbg.net
着 zhao2 (after a verb) hitting the mark / succeeding in

Answer (score 1):

When 着 was read zhao2, it means:
 1. 接触，挨上：着边。上不着天，下不着地。//one thing touches the other thing
 2. 感受，受到：着凉。着急。着忙。着风。着迷。 //be affected by something
 3. 使，派，用：别着手摸。 //using(slang)
 4. 燃烧，亦指灯发光：着火。灯着了。 //light up; 
 5. 入睡：躺下就着。 //fall asleep
 6. 用在动词后，表示达到目的或有了结果：打着了。没见着。//if used after a  verb: the motion has reached its purpose or has an result
In your sentence, I believe it takes the 6. 
So when you say 扎着, it means being pricked.

Comment: Thanks! If 着 is zhao2, how much difference do you see/understand between 被扎着 and 被扎 or 没见着 and 没见？

Comment: The difference between 被扎着 and 被扎 is that 被扎着 is something that has happened and already caused a result, while 被扎 is happening.

Comment: But for 没见, it is quite different from 没见着 because 没见 is not a proper use, but it is used in conversations. When people say 没见／没见着, it means they didn't see the thing another person is looking for, so for example when A was looking for his key, he asks B: Did you see my keys?(你见我钥匙了吗？/你见着我钥匙了吗？)，and if B didn't see it, he'll reply: 没见／没见着。　It is the same.

Comment: Problem is, this is all subjunctive, she is saying 'When（时） you get pricked you shake your hand that way' 1. 你被东西扎着时 It has not happened. Where or what is the difference between 1. and 2. 你被东西扎时就是这个样子。

Comment: You shake your hand is the reaction to "you get pricked", you're not getting pricked at the moment, but "you shake your hand" is what will happen AFTER "you get pricked", and it doesn't matter whether it is subjunctive or not.

Comment: Sorry, I still do not understand. You said above, "被扎着 is something that has happened and already caused a result," but she is referring to future instances of getting your hand pricked, ie 'When'. The future, to an English mind at least, has not yet happened. As a Chinese, do you not draw a distinction there?

Comment: Yes, actually in Chinese its normal that we use the same when referring to the past and future, we simply add the time and words that indicates time.